# WPF suppress load of databound text field on init form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Is there any way to defer the databinding until a field is changed for the first time? So basically, when the app first loads, I want the numberic textboxes to be blank instead of all being 0.

Total WPF n00b here so please change the title if there is a better way to describe the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're Observable, change the type of the numeric fields to be nullable (`int?`) and set the default value to `null` in the property definition.